# Resetting or reusing CCAnimate action

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using CCAnimate to animate my CCAnimations. What I want is reuse CCAnimate action, so, when I want to play another animation I do something like:

```
[_animateAction setAnimation:animation];
```

This works more ore less, the problem is that the internal elapsed time for the animation is not reset, setAnimation is just setting the new animation. Is there any way reset an action in cocos2D? I have been lurking through the code and documentation, and it doesn't seem to exist any method to accomplish this.

Does anyone know what is the "best practice" in this situation?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been a lot of confusion about reusing actions in Cocos2D. Apparently the docs say you should "initialize" the action again but this may not be working for all actions and it's definitely considered a bad practice to send the "init…" message to an already existing object again. This is similar to how you're not supposed to send dealloc manually to an object, yet you can do it.

Nevertheless, that's the way it is supposed to be for Cocos2D actions, so in your case to re-use the same animation action you would have to send it the appropriate init… message again:

```
[animation initWithDuration:5 animation:anim restoreOriginalFrame:YES];
[_animateAction setAnimation:animation];
```

As a side note, there's been a [suggestion for mutable actions](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=638&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Component%20Owner%20Summary) in the Cocos2D issue tracking system for two years now. The submitted code patch isn't going to work without modifications with the current Cocos2D version but it may be used to create your own mutable actions should the need arise.

Comment: Well, that is what I was thinking, but doesn't seem a good option. Not because your answers is not good, but the way cocos do this. Thanks for your time anyway, I think I will try to accomplish this myself. I will tag this as correct because not being a good solution to the problem, at the moment is the only one if you don't code your own animation system.